# How to render an environment only pass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, render-passes

I'm having trouble rendering an environment only pass.
The problem I'm having is that objects in the scene will cause the environment pass to include blacked out regions where they're positioned.

Is there a way of having the environment pass rendered completely without objects masking out certain regions?

[image]

Comment: Render a layer that contains no objects and has environment pass enabled.

Comment: @cegaton it works, I'm wondering what passes I can uncheck to boost render times though. I've unchecked everything and excluded all scene layers. I've only checked the environment lighting pass and 'use environment' (render sky in this layer). Am I forgetting something?

Comment: @cegaton If you can put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!